# Property overriding in swift

Tags: swift

I have a `DataSource` protocol that contains a `data` property of `Any` type:

```
protocol DataSource {
    var data: Any? { get }
}
```

Then I want to implement this protocol with a class that restricts the data type to a certain type:

```
class IntDataSource: DataSource {
    var data: Int?
}
```

But the compiler claims it doesn't conform to the protocol, but `Int` conforms to the `Any` type.

Why can't I override the type of swift properties?

Comment: I don't know if it helps, but Mike Ash wrote a great post about that topic: https://www.mikeash.com/pyblog/friday-qa-2015-11-20-covariance-and-contravariance.html

Comment: Maybe specify: `{ get }`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Using wildcard type like `Any` should be avoided almost always and prefer generic solutions, leveraging swift's type system.

```
protocol DataSource {
  typealias DataType
  var data: DataType? { get }
}

class IntDataSource: DataSource {
  var data: Int?
}
```

Swift allows [**associated type**](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/Generics.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40014097-CH26-ID189) for `protocol` to solve exactly the problem that you have. And thanks to its type inference, often explicitly defining abstracted type is unnecessary (in this case concrete type of `DataType` is inferred from `var data: Int?`).

Answer (score 1):

A possible variation on the `DataType` answer could be to solve it with a generic function.

```
protocol DataSource {
    func getData<T> () -> [T]
}

class IntDataSource<Int>: DataSource {
    func getData<Int>() -> [Int] {
        let data:[Int] = [1, 1, 2, 3]
        return data
    }
}
```

Just for trivia, I think you should use `DataType`solution